# Can i use the api java 'jena' in flutter mobile application

Tags: java, flutter, jena

I want to create application mobile with flutter but i need api java which is jena, so can we use library java.. In flutter if yes, so how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to communicate with native interfaces of your app, but looking at the library, that's probably not a good idea.

More drawbacks:

- You have to implement native code twice, for Android (Java/Kotlin) and iOS (ObjC/Swift). **That means an app depending on Apache Jena will only work on Android if you don't find a counterpart that works natively on iOS.**
- All communication through platform channels is asynchronous, which increases complexity.
- When the API of the java library is complex, you end up duplicating a lot of code.

If your app heavily depends on Apache Jena, you have a few options:

- Create a Backend Service in Java that does the processing which requires Apache Jena. Send the result to your Flutter client.
- Write a native Android app that directly uses the library. Drop iOS.
- Port the parts of Apache Jena that your app needs to Dart (probably too complex)

Comment: @DjamilaJada did you considered accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a [Flutter plugin](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/) that exposes the [Jena](https://jena.apache.org) API to your Dart code base over [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/).

The bad news is that at least as of November 2018, [no such Flutter plugin exists](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=jena) as yet.

The bottom line is that, yes, it's technically doable, but you would need to create the plugin yourself or motivate somebody to create it.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a plugin. You can just add the platform-specific code to the "android" project of your Flutter workspace.